# While trying to create a txt file with input it doesn't work

Tags: python, python-3.x

I wanted to create a program that saves the user input, im using sublime text 3 and python 3.9, when I run the program the text file with the user input is not appending in the folder that i saved my program

```
filename = "proba.txt"
name = input("Give me your name. ")
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write(f" {name.title()}\n")
```

[this is the code that i tried to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q60LC.png)

sorry for not showing the code here but i ran into problems while trying to rewrite the code here (it was illegible).

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me

Comment: What is the error? (also, what OS?)

Comment: Your program won’t save to a file where the program is, rather , from where you run the program. Have you searched your file system for all occurrences of the file?

Comment: to be more specific, i saved the .py in folder python_projects and from there i ran the program, so I was expecting the txt. file from the user input will append there right after closing the program and it doesn't happen.

Comment: and one more thing when i create a program without user input it works fine and instantly creates txt file in specified folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine for me. But sometimes it makes sense to point a destination folder explicitly, just to be sure. I used to do it with `pathlib` module:

```
from pathlib import Path

current_folder = Path.cwd() # the folder from which the script was started
filename = current_folder / "proba.txt"
name = input("Give me your name. ")
with open(filename, "a") as f:
    f.write(f" {name.title()}\n")
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

**Update**

As for your case, it looks like you're trying to run the code in VSCode via meny `Run code` or something like this. Alas, `input()` doesn't work this way. You need to use `Run Python File in Terminal`:

[image]

Or you can use `cmd.exe` or `powershell` or `Terminal app` and run the python code from there:

```
python make_file_proba.py
```

For MacOS it will be likely:

```
python3 make_file_proba.py
```

Comment: BIG THANKS!! the idea with running program with cmd solved the problem.